# Sharing files from ubuntu running in VmWare to the host running OS X?

Tags: ubuntu, file-sharing, vmware-workstation

What is the easiest way to share folders from a Server Install of Ubuntu (no x-windows) running inside VMWare, to the host computer running OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up an [NFS share on OS X](http://www.behanna.org/osx/nfs/howto1.html) for the Ubuntu VM would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Adding a "host only" network interface device to the VM would allow this regardless of network connectivity (meaning the share will be non-LAN dependent)

Comment: Good thinking Christian, completely forgot about that (duh moment :D)
Brad, a detailed overview on setting up Ubuntu+sharing folders in OS X is here: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread82083.html#

Answer (score 1):

you can use vmwares [shared folder](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html).